# Link Image not solid

Tags: html, image, css, hyperlink, hover

I don't know how to explain what's happening, but I have a logo image on my site and when you hover over some of it, it works right, but if you hover over some of the other parts it doesn't act like a link. It acts on it randomly so it's not like half of the image is just not a link or something it's like hover over the letter "P" it works hover over "in" it doesn't work hover over "kT" it works again (the logo says "Pink Tangerine").

It's a png with a transparent background so I'm wondering if that has something to so with it, but that doesn't make any sense. I've never ran into a problem like this before, can you guys tell me what's wrong?

HTML5

```
<div id="main-banner">
    <header>
        <a id="image" href="index.html">
            <img alt="Logo" src="Images/PT-logo.png">
        </a>        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About_Us/about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact_US/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS3

I don't imagine most of my CSS should be relevant, but I included all the link description and main header/banner stuff just in case. The one class that deals with the image is at the bottom of the CSS and it only makes it so I don't get a weird border when I hover over the image.

```
/*Link Info */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DB7093;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFC0CB;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #DB7093;
    color: #F0F8FF;
}

/*Banner Navigation*/

#main-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 25px 0 0;
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
}

#main-banner header {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

#main-banner header img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#main-banner header nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    left: 105px;
    top: 50px;
}

#main-banner header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
}

#main-banner header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

#main-banner header nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #DB7093;
    color: #F0F8FF;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#main-banner header nav ul li a {
    color: #DB7093;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    height: 12px;
}

/*Image Links*/

a#image {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Does the problem appear in this demo? My guess is that some other element on your page is obscuring part of the logo image, but I don't see that here. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bL2j6/

Comment: The nav tag is seemingly causing the lapses in the link as I'm seeing it here http://jsfiddle.net/7FBXL/

Comment: Yeah it's happening in the demo, hover over the x for example.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is the nav tag and the left/top/height css style, because it's container is the same as the image link so there is overlap.

removing the left/top/height fixes it as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FBXL/1/). It depends on what your ultimate goal is as far as looks go in order to fix it and still have the appearance you want.

```
    #main-banner header nav {
    position: relative;     
}
```

EDIT:
I would think using some margin to move the element would get you what you want, just not sure where the placement is supposed to go.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing this out, I've never had this happen before and I've used this coding process quite a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to something Charles380 pointed out. I made the image absolute and just the nav relative so I could move it like I wanted. Thanks for your help guys.